# Customize notification alert title in push notification firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working on push notification's in iOS Swift using Firebase. On firebase token i successfully received notification in app. Using php service i received payload message which includes title. Same title is shown in notification alert. How can i customize that title from the code once received payload message.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can't change the alert title from your project, it has to be changed on the backend.

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about the same thing but want to confirm before move forward